# Prove that if $3|a^2-b^2$, $8|a^2-b^2$, then $24|a^2-b^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

if $3|a^2-b^2$, $8|a^2-b^2$, then $24|a^2-b^2$. Is it something can be proved?
If so, please give me a guide line.

Comment: You have that $(3,8)=1$. Do you know an theorems concerning this?

Comment: You mean gcd(3,8)=1?

Comment: If you do a prime factor decomposition of $a^2-b^2$, how often does the $2$ occur? Or the $3$? What does that tell you?

Answer (score 1):

As $\gcd(3,8)=1$ there exists integers $x,y$ so that $3x+8y=1$. [Note that $x=3, y=-1$ work in this case, but I will keep $x,y$ so that the same proof works in general].

Now, since $8|a^2-b^2$ we have $a^2-b^2=8c$ for some integer $c$. Similarly $a^2-b^2=3d$ for some integer $d$.

Then

$$a^2-b^2=(3x+8y)(a^2-b^2)=3(a^2-b^2)x+8(a^2-b^2)y=3\cdot 8cx+8 \cdot 3dy =24(cd+dy)$$

**P.S.** The same approach can prove the more general result: If $n|a, m|a$ and $gcd(m,n)=1$ then $mn|a$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, $a|x$, and $b|x$, then $ab|x$.

Comment: In this case, $gcd(3,8)=1$, $3|x$, and $8|x$, then $24|x$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$3|a^2-b^2 \iff a^2-b^2 = 3p$ for some integer $p$ (by definition).

$8|a^2-b^2 \iff a^2-b^2 = 8q$ for some integer $q$ (by definition).

$24|a^2-b^2 \iff a^2-b^2 = 24r$ for some integer $r$ (by definition).

Answer (score 0):

Let $c=a^2-b^2$. Then,
$$
3|c \Rightarrow c=3p
$$

for some $p$. Similarly, $$ 8|c \Rightarrow c=8q$$
for some $q$. Since 3 does not divide 8, that must mean that $c=a^2-b^2$ contains $3\times 8$ such that it can be written as $$a^2-b^2=3\times 8\times r$$
and hence, since 3 times 8 is 24, it follows that
$$
a^2-b^2=24r \Rightarrow 24|(a^2-b^2).
$$